# Why I have tp provide username/password to push my changes when I have ssh set?

Tags: git

I need to push my project into gitlab with ssh and for this I created a new ssh-key(I suppose old was expired)

with command :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "Master ssh key"
default enter : Enter file in which to save the key (/home/master/.ssh/id_rsa):

Enter file in which to save the key (/home/master/.ssh/id_rsa):
...
```

and I created new ssh key under my gitlab account profile page
https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys/NNNNNNN :
https://prnt.sc/CpPzb-ZktSY0

But When I try to push my commands with command :

```
 git push -uf origin master
```

it opened console for username/password filling.

I run manually command

```
service ssh restart
```

and reopened console again

but I still need to provide username/password to push my changes.

But I can easily clone other project without providing username/password  ?

What is wrong ? does it depend on properties of the repository ? I am owner of both repositories mentioned...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you _added_ (with `ssh-add`) the private key before pushing?

Comment: No. Please point all commands I need to run

Comment: `ssh-add the-private-key-file`. If the certificate was created with a password, it will ask for it, then it is _added_. Then it will be used by git when you try to do stuff through ssh (and would presumably work when pushing if the public certificate key correctly set in the repo hosting provider and you are using ssh as the transport for the repo).

Comment: to debug ssh issue : try running `ssh -v git@gitlab.com`.

Comment: Use the command-line `ssh` command to debug your ssh setup. Then, *once that works*, introduce Git: make sure your *URL* is an *ssh URL*, because Git will use https or ssh depending on the URL you use.